# Java based mobile app+IIS server

Tags: java, .net, iis, java-me, mobile-application

I want to develop a mobile application which can work in GPS/GPRS based phones. I heard like Java is the most suitable platform to develop that. But I want to connect this mobile application to the IIS server. Is it possible?

I have one more query.
Is it possible to deploy applications developed using .net mobile in basic gps phones?

Comment: ya..ok..but iam completely new to this java and mobile app development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.

In order to communicate with your IIS server ,

1. you can create webservice and deploy it over IIS and consume it from j2me app/
2. you can use URLConnection to make GET POST request to your IIS Server from J2ME Application.

First one is more preferable.

- [Introduction to J2ME Web Services](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/)

Comment: There won't be any compatibility issues with a ASP.NET site and a j2me mobile app?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/28046) tutorial for reference and quick start, its too old but you can get many thing from it